# Galaxy s4 compatible sdcards

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, sd-card

I'm thinking about buying this:

[http://www.amazon.com/PNY-Elite-Performance-256GB-Speed/dp/B00FF90EZM/ref=sr_1_3?s=pc&ie=UTF8&qid=1417386617&sr=1-3&keywords=sd+card](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00FF90EZM)

Is the 256gb  compatible with galaxy s4? I'm concerned that it might not be because I've never heard of anyone using such a high gb card with the s4.

Thanks

Comment: I think you want a micro sd card. Not the one you chose.

Comment: @rrirower Ahh cool. http://www.amazon.com/Samsung-Class-Adapter-MB-MP64DA-AM/dp/B00IVPU7AO/ref=sr_1_1?s=pc&ie=UTF8&qid=1417400166&sr=1-1&keywords=micro+sd So something like this would be good?

Comment: Exactly. But, I'd save some money by going with a 16gb card. That's usually sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

I just put a 256gb micro sd in mine today, it works so far. But it has to be a micro sd not the one you have a link to. I've been trying to look up what the galaxy 4 can support, to see if I'll have problems as I fill it up. Haven't found anything yet.